# Where is the iptables log in OpenSuSe?

Tags: iptables, logging, opensuse

I try to find iptables log for this rule:

```
8    LOG        tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:3307 flags:0x17/0x02 LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP "
9    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:3307
```

I was try to found needed connection statistics by next command:

```
journalctl | grep  3307
```

But it is no give needed results for me. In OpenSuSe missing files */var/log/messages, /var/log/iptables*.
Where I can find and view iptables log?

Comment: /var/log/firewall ?

Comment: @yagmoth555 No, this folder not exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, after rsyslog install  *var/log/firewall* was created. Second solution is use *journalctl*:

```
sudo journalctl --since="today" --until="2016-08-19 10:00:00" | grep ACC-TCP
```